# Android emulator black screen with "GPU emulation - yes"

Tags: android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, gpu, android-virtual-device, emulation

I'm trying to use the new feature of the android avd features "GPU emulation - yes"
It's needed to use GLES2.0 on the emulator.
However, when I turn that on, the screen of the emulator goes blank.
[Here is the output when I call it from command line.](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/no-eglconfig-found-t6129-40.html#p33241)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same problem and having a nvidia card with optimus...
Just install ironhide!

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/ironhide
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ironhide
```

Then follow the instructions and reboot! Magic happens! But it's hard sometimes!

Comment: Did you get it running with Android 2.3.3 emulator, or 4.0.3+? I can't get 2.3.3 to run with gpu.

Comment: Both. If your configuration and/or the output when you call it from the command line is different from mine, I recommend you to open a new question with the details.

Comment: I did, but I'm trying to do this in Windows and there's no ironhide for Windows :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184036/android-2-3-3-emulator-with-x86-image-wont-run-with-use-host-gpu#comment21391931_15184036