# Android SDK Emulator with OpenGL ES 2.0 Support?

Tags: android, android-emulator

recently while reading some tutorials online, I saw this video suggesting that the Android SDK now supports OpenGL ES 2.0:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=T--vFtyZvc4

Enthusiastically, I added the option for 'GPU Emulation' in my emulator and tried to run a basic HelloOpenGLES20 app, however I was greeted with this error, and some null pointer exceptions which doesn't make sense:

```
Sorry!
The application
LessonOneActivity (process
lesson.One has stopped
unexpectedly. Please try again.

Force close
```

The app runs fine on a real Android phone displaying some spinning triangles, I'm wondering if anyone has encountered the problem I'm facing, I've did a fair share of googling but could find no solutions =(

Here's the log:

```
04-26 06:42:08.782: D/AndroidRuntime(577): Shutting down VM
04-26 06:42:08.813: W/dalvikvm(577): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {lesson.One/com.learnopengles.android.lesson1.LessonOneActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:512)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at com.learnopengles.android.lesson1.LessonOneActivity.onResume(LessonOneActivity.java:46)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-26 06:42:08.842: E/AndroidRuntime(577):  ... 12 more
04-26 06:42:13.292: I/Process(577): Sending signal. PID: 577 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you please post the exceptions info?

Answer (score 0):

I have run the code, and the exception is due to the fact that the emulator still does not support GLES20.  If you print more information, you'll see that `supportsEs2` is false.

Why the emulator does not support GLES20 even if `GPU Emulation` is set to true is system-dependent.  If you are developing on Linux, it may be related to the graphics card.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179187/android-emulator-black-screen-with-gpu-emulation-yes) is a similar question with some possible solutions.  At least you can try it.

EDIT:

According to [the official site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics), you need to set your emulator target to API 15 (rev03) or higher.

Comment: Oh well, I guess that's that =(
I'm not on Linux but thanks for the help!

Comment: I've finally found the problem, it turns out it's some weird conflict caused by my firewall, when I turn it off, the app runs perfectly, now I just have to find a way to make them play nicely without having to turn my zonealarm off...

Comment: Firewall?  Well, glad that you worked it out, though I'm a little confused.

Comment: Me too, but it turns out it's an outright incompatibility with the firewall, I unplugged my internet and disabled every feature so that I could be sure that the firewall wasn't blocking anything, yet it just wouldn't run! Ended up ditching it in the end.

Comment: @Hobbyist Graphic Card is Required to run the OPenGL? in emulator am also having the same problem can u please help me on this Thank you,