# Problems with Android Emulator with GPU enabled

Tags: android, mobile

Problems with Android Emulator with GPU enabled.
Summary & Details:

- GPU Emulation is ON and the image used is ARM EABI it continously blinks. The same problem as stated here: [Android emulator black screen with "GPU emulation - yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179187/android-emulator-black-screen-with-gpu-emulation-yes). But the difference is that I'm running the emulator on a Windows 7 instead of Linux.
- GPU Emulation is ON and the image used is INTEL x86 ATOM (w/o intel virtualization) it continously blinks the same as the previous.
- GPU Emulation is ON and the image used is INTEL x86 ATOM with INTEL VIRTUALIZATION enabled (installed intel haxm and set the virtualization on at the BIOS config) results in a BLUE SCREEN CRASH.
- I'm running Windows 7 x64 with SP1 installed.
- Tried API 15 and API16.
- Android SDK Tools rev 20.0.1 (latest)
- Android SDK Platformtools 13 (latest)

This, if solved, would definately save my time developing. Please help.

Comment: My Mac mini was sent for repairs and now I'm having a similar problem in a temp Windows box I'm using, its w7 64bit, same graphics chip as the mac (intel's i7 hd3000 on die). It keeps blinking black sometimes , I managed to enable virtualization tho, its fast but shows these artifacts.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only recently. Initially it wasn't so, but after the last update is started blinking like hell. Turning host GPU off solves the issue, but of course, that's not a solution :(. Seems some settings get messed up. Maybe a reinstall would solve this?