# Android 2.3.3 emulator with x86 image won't run with "Use host GPU"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I noticed that if I check the "Use host GPU" checkbox when creating a new virtual device with Android 2.3.3 and Intel x86 system image, the emulator just won't run, it shows black screen with no signs of life, aside from errors in logcat. According to some information that I found online, running on host GPU was never intended to work for 2.3.3 images, only 4.0.3+. But then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179187/android-emulator-black-screen-with-gpu-emulation-yes) where the author claims to successfully run it after installing `ironhide`. But ironhide, which I've never had a chance to use and don't quite know what it actually is, is only available on Linux.
Is there any way to run 2.3.3 with x86 system image and host GPU enabled on Windows?

Comment: FWIW, I get the same black screen when trying this combination on Mac OS X.

Comment: ironhide is only needed in linux when using a nvidia card with optimus. In windows you should be fine by keeping your drivers up to date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the graphics acceleration feature, you must have the following versions of the Android development tools installed:
Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher
Android SDK Platform API 15, Revision 3 or higher

Comment: "Android SDK Platform API 15, Revision 3 or higher" so you're saying that GPU acceleration is physically not supported on API10 emulator. Where does this information come from? Can you post a link to official documentation?

Comment: [Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics).

Comment: You can still do it. Just run Emulator in command prompt with the following: emulator -avd DEVICENAME -gpu host

Answer (score 3):

Just uncheck the "Use Host GPU", as its intended for Android 4+. Emulator is fast enough on this combination even if you dont use host gpu and you set enough RAM when installing HAXM and disable the animation.